# SQL Simple Join with two tables, but one is random

Tags: sql-server, join

I am stuck with this. I have a simple set-up with two tables. One table is holding emailaddresses one table is holding vouchercodes. I want to join them in a third table, so that each emailaddress has one random vouchercode.

Unfortunatly I am stuck with this as there are no identic Ids to match both values. What I have so far brings no result:

```
Select 
A.Email
B.CouponCode
FROM Emailaddresses as A
JOIN CouponCodes as B
on A.Email = B.CouponCode
```

A hint would be great as search did not bring me any further yet.

Edit -

```
Table A (Addresses)
-------------------
Column A         | Column B
------------------------- 
email1@gmail.com  True
email2@gmail.com
email3@gmail.com  True
email4@gmail.com



Table B (Voucher)
-------------------
ABCD1234
ABCD5678
ABCD9876
ABCD5432



Table C
-------------------------
column A | column B
-------------------------

email1@gmail.com  ABCD1234
email2@gmail.com  ABCD5678
email3@gmail.com  ABCD9876
email4@gmail.com  ABCD5432
```

Sample Data:

Comment: maybe some sample data would help here

Comment: thx for input, I added some sample data.

Comment: You need to have something common in between these two tables to `JOIN`, the query provided by you just doesn't work!

Comment: I can confirm that @Thorsten code is working. I now want to add a WHERE clause in that piece, but receiving errors. Where do I need to add WHERE Column B = 'TRUE' . Appreciated!

Comment: can TableA have more record than B or vice versa?  What do you want to have happen to the "extra/Missing"? values?

Comment: TableA can not have more records. TableB can have more records, as there should always be Codes available. What do you mean by "extra/MIssing"? The ones that are not tagged as  'TRUE' ?

Comment: xQbert means: if you have 4 records in A and 5 records in B, what is supposed to happen? Pick 4 B records arbitrarily, so we show only four result rows? Or use one A record twice, so we can show five result rows? Or something else still?

Comment: Ok, each record in B should only be used once. If we have 4 records in A and 5 in B, there should be 4 records picked from B. No record either A or B should be used twice.

Answer (score 2):

While joining without proper keys is not a good solution, for your case you can try this. (note: not tested, just a quick suggestion)

```
;with cte_email as (
    select row_number() over (order by Email) as rownum, Email
    from Emailaddresses 
)
;with cte_coupon as (
    select row_number() over (order by CouponCode) as rownum, CouponCode
    from CouponCodes 
)

select a.Email,b.CouponCode
from cte_email a
join cte_coupon b
on a.rownum = b.rownum
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a row number for both the tables and join it with row number.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        order by [Column_A]
    ), *
    from [Table_A]
),
cte2 as(
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        order by [Column_A]
    ), *
    from [Table_B]
)
select t1.[Column_A] as [Email_Id], t2.[Column_A] as [Coupon]
from cte t1
join cte2 t2
on t1.rn = t2.rn;
```

**[Find a demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/768237/sql-simple-join-with-two-tables-but-one-is-random)**

Answer (score 1):

You want to randomly join records, one email with one coupon each. So create random row numbers and join on these:

```
select 
  e.email,
  c.couponcode
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as rn from emailaddresses t) e
join (select t.*, row_number() over (order by newid()) as rn from CouponCodes t) c
  on c.rn = e.rn;
```

Comment: I can confirm this code is working (I am not allowed to upvote yet, sorry). Thank you Thorsten. Do you have an Idea how I can expand that code with an WHERE clause for the emailaddresses table?

Comment: I edited the sample Data so it is clear what I mean. The Where Clause would say :Where Column B = 'true'

Comment: Well, so add a `WHERE` clause: `from emailaddresses where columnb = 'true'`.

Comment: just add your where clause at the end, do you get any errors if you do so ?

Comment: I can confirm that it works at the end. Not so directly behind the "from emailaddresses".'

Thanks @GuidoG

Comment: I should work just the same. Maybe it's because I forgot to include the table alias in my comment and you simply copy-pasted without considering this. On the other hand you would probably have got an error message explaing that t.* is undefined. Anyway, `from emailaddresses t where columnb = 'true'` should work.